# How to create and publish a Vuejs component on NPM

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, dependencies, vuejs2

I started working a lot with `vue` and started to use it in all the projects in the company where I work. And with that, I ended up creating some `components`, in general `autocomplete`, I know that there are many, I have already used some, but none have supplied all my needs. However, whenever I go to work on a new project and use the same component, either I recreates it, or I copy and paste it.

So I came to doubt How to create my component, upload to npmjs for whenever I use it, just give a `npm install -save ...`, and also be able to contribute a bit with the community.

Comment: You want to know how to (all the steps) publish and use import to import a library from NPM right?

Comment: No, i'm know how to publish, just do not know what the structure should be for reuse

Comment: Ok. I'm cooking up something and trying it along the way to make sure the code works. But I will basically be guiding you to publish then install your component and import it into your vue app, does that work for you?

Comment: Yes, Very Thanks

Comment: @samayo I have not tested yet, I'll test today.

Comment: @samayo to do using vue CLI with webpack?

Comment: No need for vue-cli if you want to publish or use this example. Just install NPM and follow the examples

Comment: @samayo Cool, Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### update

With the release of vue-loader 15.x this answer will no longer work. Please use this instead https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-a-vue-js-app-using-single-file-components-without-the-cli-7e73e5b8244f

---

Here is one way you can create/publish a Vuejs library/component from scratch.

As I am going to write down every step and command, make sure to follow the entire guide and you will be able to create and publish your own Vuejs component on NPM.

After you publish it, like most libraries you can install it using ex:

```
npm install --save your-component
```

And then import the component inside your app using

```
import something from 'your-component'
```

---

To start creating our first component, first create a folder called `vuejs-hello-app` (or any other name) and inside it, run:

```
npm init
```

Just hit enter until the interactive question ends and then npm will generate a file named `package.json` in that folder containing the following code.

> (Note: I changed the description and version from `1.0.0` to `0.1.0` here is the result.)

```
{
  "name": "vuejs-hello-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "vuejs library demo",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

After this, we'll need to install the dependencies for our library.

These dependencies are divided into two types: `dependency` and `devDependency`

`dependency`:
 is the external library or libraries that our own component runs on. When someone installs your component, npm will make sure this dependency exists or gets installed first. Since we are creating a component for vue, we need to make sure vue is required. So, install it using:

```
npm install --save vue
```

`devDependency`:
 is a bunch of libraries that we need only for development purposes. These libraries will help us build and/or transpile.

We install dev dependencies using the method above by adding the the suffix `-dev` to `--save`

Now, let us install the minimum dev dependencies we need for our component:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-core
npm install --save-dev babel-loader
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env
npm install --save-dev cross-env
npm install --save-dev css-loader
npm install --save-dev file-loader
npm install --save-dev node-sass
npm install --save-dev sass-loader
npm install --save-dev vue-loader
npm install --save-dev vue-template-compiler
npm install --save-dev webpack
npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server
```

At this point the libraries will be installed and the `package.json` will be updated to look like following.

```
{
  "name": "vuejs-hello-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "vuejs library demo",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "vue-loader": "^13.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.9",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.9"
  }
}
```

> (note: I have added `"build": "webpack -p"` to build our lib with webpack)

Now, since our code needs to be built and transpiled, we need a folder to store the build version. Go ahead and create a folder inside our root folder and call it: `dist` and in the same place a configuration file for webpack and name it `webpack.config.js`

All of the files we have so far created are for configuring and stuff. For the actual app that people are going to use, we need to create at least two files inside our `src/` directory.

A `main.js` and `VuejsHelloApp.vue` put them as: 
`./src/main.js` and `./src/components/VuejsHelloApp.vue`

I have mine structured like this:

```
dist
node_modules
src
  main.js
  components
    VuejsHelloApp.vue
.babelrc
.eslintignore
.gitignore
.npmignore
.travis.yml
CONTRIBUTING
LICENSE
package.json
README.md
webpack.config.js
```

I will just go through the files listed and describe what each file does in-case anyone is curious:

`/dist` is where a build (transpiled), minified, non-ES6 version of your code will be stores

`node_modules` I think we know this already, let's ignore it

`src/` this is root dir of your library.

`.babelrc` is where your babel options are kept, so add this to disable presets on modules

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

`.eslintignore` This is where you tell ESLINT to ignore linting so put this inside:

```
build/*.js
```

`.gitignore` 
 add files you want to ignore (from git)

`.npmignore` same as .gitignore for NPM

`.travis.yml` if you need CI check [examples](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/) from travis and configure it

`CONTRIBUTING` not required

`LICENSE` not required

`package.json`   ignore for now

`README.md` not required

`webpack.config.js` This is the important file that let's you create a build, browser compatible version of your code.

So, according to our app, here is a minimal example of what it should look like:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',

  module: {
    rules: [
      // use babel-loader for js files
      { test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
      // use vue-loader for .vue files
      { test: /\.vue$/, use: 'vue-loader' }
    ]
  },
  // default for pretty much every project
  context: __dirname,
  // specify your entry/main file
  output: {
    // specify your output directory...
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    // and filename
    filename: 'vuejs-hello-app.js'
  }
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Note that the important directives here are `entry` and `output`. You can check webpack docs to learn more if you want to fully customize your app.

But basically, we're telling webpack to get the `./src/main.js` (our app) and output it as `./dist/vuejs-hello-app.js`

Now, we are almost finished setting up everything except the actual app.

Go to `/src/components/VuejsHelloApp.vue` and dump this simple app, which will move a button right or left when you hover on it

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @mouseover='move($event)'> I'm alive </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
   return {}
  },

  methods: {
    move (event) {
        let pos = event.target.style.float; 
      if(pos === 'left'){
        event.target.style.float = 'right'
      }else{
        event.target.style.float = 'left'
      }
    }
  }
}

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

And not but not least, got to `./src/main.js` and export your app like:

```
import VuejsHelloApp from './components/VuejsHelloApp.vue'
export default VuejsHelloApp
```

Now go to your `package.json` file replace the `"main: "index.js",` with `"main": "src/main.js",`

After this, simply run these commands to build and publish your app:

```
npm run build
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push -u origin master
npm login 
npm publish
```

---

#### Importing and using the library.

If everything went smoothly, then simply install your app like this:

```
npm install --save vuejs-hello-app
```

And use it in vue like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <VuejsHelloApp> </VuejsHelloApp>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VuejsHelloApp from 'vuejs-hello-app'
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  components: { VuejsHelloApp }
}
</script>
```

---

I made this app https://github.com/samayo/vuejs-hello-app while writing the answer, it might help to better understand the code

Comment: Great tutorial. You forget the to add `"build": "webpack -p"` in package.sjon in order to run `npm build`

Comment: Thanks and nice catch. Just fixed it

Comment: A plugin is now required for vue-loader
https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/migrating.html#a-plugin-is-now-required

Comment: @samayo that's a great tutorial 
there is a great tutorial to do so with Vue typescript component?

Comment: @Erez Thanks, I haven't tried vue typescript yet, and I don't know if there is a similar tutorial

Comment: Maybe not what most are interested in, but in order to complete the reply, can you cover how would you also setup the testing part of further development the component eg. multiple entry and outputs for webpack, so the authors can maintain their components.

Comment: For starters or anyone wondering how to keep developing and meantime building the component package checkout https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/multiple-entry-points on how to run webpack on multiple entries.

Comment: thanks, i don't know how to test vue components yet so i did not include that and also the question was about building a component so i wanted to stay on topic, but once i find out i will add more to the answer and will checkout your link

Comment: Thank you for these great instructions. What would you do if inside the `VuejsHelloApp.vue` file you would need to import another Vue file? If I do so the imported Vue file is not added to the `src` folder.

Comment: @phpheini Hey, sorry I didn't get notification about your comment, I just saw it now. Anyway, if you want to import a file in a `.vue` folder, you can. Just make sure the dir is in the right place. You can use `./a/b/foo.js`

Comment: How should we run develop mode for this project? 

https://github.com/samayo/vuejs-hello-app/issues/2