# Importing an NPM package with a Vue Component in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, vue.js

I made my own NPM package with a Vue component inside. At first I didn't use any building system, it was just a basic package with `package.json` and an `src` folder with a single *.vue component file and a main file `index.js`. I was exporting the component like this in my `index.js`:

```
module.exports = require('./TagsInput.vue');
```

The component worked fine when I installed it into a Laravel project.

Then I decided to use the `webpack-simple` vue-cli template to be able to build my package into the `dist` folder and I can't get things to work. The package builds fine when I build it from the package folder. But in Laravel I started getting this error:

```
TypeError: "exports" is read-only
```

Then I changed the `index.js` to this:

```
import TagsInput from './TagsInput.vue'

Vue.config.keyCodes.backspace = 8;
Vue.component('tags-input', TagsInput);

export { TagsInput }

export default TagsInput
```

And now I'm getting this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <TagsInput>
...
```

Comment: You should not have two exports in your index.js. Make sure to check this answer which allows you to create a vue npm library from scratch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754244/how-to-create-and-publish-a-vuejs-component-on-npm/47757050#47757050 maybe you will find where the error is comming from

Comment: I saw the 2 exports in someone else's package. I tried it with a single export, nothing I was able to google worked so far. The package builds and works fine outside of Laravel.